# Can the modulus of an entire function of the form $ze^{g(z)}$ tend to $1$ in the upper half-plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, examples-counterexamples, harmonic-functions, entire-functions

Does there exist an entire function $g$ such that $|ze^{g(z)}| = 1 + o(1)$ as $\text{Im}(z)\to+\infty$?

Question can be reformulated in terms of $u(z) = \text{Re}(g(z))$. Namely, does there exist a harmonic in $\mathbb{C}$ function $u$ such that $u(z) = -\log(|z|) + o(1)$ as $ \text{Im}(z)\to+\infty $? In this case the function $-u$ is positive in some half-plane $\{\text{Im}(z) > N\}$ and therefore $-u$ admits the Herglotz representation without the linear term there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. For $\Im(z) > 0$ let

$$g(z) = -\log z + \int_{i\infty}^z \frac{e^{is}}{s}ds$$

$\int_{i\infty}^{x+iy} \frac{e^{is}}{s}ds= \int_{i\infty}^{iy}\frac{e^{is}}{s}ds
-i \frac{e^{is}}{s}|_{iy}^{x+iy}-i\int_{iy}^{x+iy}\frac{e^{is}}{s^2}ds$ converges to $0$ uniformly as $y\to \infty$.

So $z e^{g(z)} = e^{o(1)}$ as $\Im(z)\to \infty$.

$g(z)$ extends to an entire function because $$g'(z)= \frac{e^{iz}-1}z$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is a very nice construction! Can it probably be modified so that $ze^{g(z)} = 1 +o(1)$ as $|z|\to\infty$ in $\{\Im z > 0\}$?

Comment: Yes integrate by parts as I did it will give $g(z)=-\log z + O(1/|z|)$ uniformly on $\Im(z) \ge c$ for any fixed $c$